# How to render a radio button choice in Django Modelform based on enum field defined at the model level?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have an enum field ("type") defined at the model level like below, how should I implement the corresponding ModelForm field in my model field? Actually the rendered HTML code don't output radio button and wraps this field within an empty list. Should "replicate" the enum choices within the form class in order to populate radio button choices, is there another to take advantage of choices already defined at the model level?

**Rendered HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_type_0">Type</label>
    <ul id="id_type" class="form-control">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)

    TYPE_LIST =  [ 
        ('EXT_CL', 'Customer'), 
        ('INT_TP', 'Internal third party'), 
        ('INT_OW', 'Owner'),      
    ]  

    type = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=TYPE_LIST,default='EXT_CL')  

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'foos'
        fields = ('name','type')

    def __str__(self):
        object_name = self.name 
        return object_name
```

**forms.py**

```
class FooCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.label_suffix = ''

        self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(label='Name',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }))
        self.fields['type'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Type',required=True,widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }))   

        class Meta(object):
            model = Foos
            fields = ('name','type')

        def clean_name(self):
            name = self.cleaned_data['name']
            return name

        def clean_type(self):
            type = self.cleaned_data['type']
            return type
```

**template.html**

```
<form id="foo-create-form" method="post" action=" " role="form">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ foo_create_form.name.label_tag }}
        {{ foo_create_form.name }}

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ foo_create_form.type.label_tag }}
        {{ foo_create_form.type }}
    </div>   
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the choices in `forms.py` instead of `models.py`

```
class FooCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.label_suffix = ''

    TYPE_LIST =  [ 
    ('EXT_CL', 'Customer'), 
    ('INT_TP', 'Internal third party'), 
    ('INT_OW', 'Owner'),      
]  

    self.fields['name'] = forms.CharField(label='Name',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }))
    self.fields['type'] = forms.ChoiceField(label='Type',choice=TYPE_LIST, required=True,widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={ 'class': 'form-control' }))   

    class Meta(object):
        model = Foos
        fields = ('name','type')

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        return name

    def clean_type(self):
        type = self.cleaned_data['type']
        return type
```